# Insert to microsoft sql server user database failed

Tags: sql-server, yii2-advanced-app

Why I can't add more than one user to yii2 application? I'm using microsoft sql server and the signup code for yii2 app has not changed yet. When there is no record in user table, I can add user by using signup page from yii.
this is the DB script

```
    USE [IBR]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[user]    Script Date: 11/05/2016 16.51.02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [username] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [auth_key] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [password_hash] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [password_reset_token] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [status] [smallint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((10)),
    [created_at] [int] NOT NULL,
    [updated_at] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [password_reset_token] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [email] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [username] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

this is the screenshot.[error while signup for 2nd times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kduD.png)

Comment: what you didn't understood from the error? the error itself tells you that you are using a duplicate value for an unique column

Comment: seems like your query violate the unique constraint of the table. check if there is already an entry in the table for username "Tari"

Comment: Looks like you're not inserting data into your Primary Key at all. Check out your table structure and work out where that PK is. You'll need to insert a unique value, at the moment you're trying to insert a NULL but there's already one in there.

Comment: @KandarpPatel : the problem is, I think I'm not using duplicate value.

Comment: @bmsqldev : no, there is no entry for that username. I think it is connected to the primary key, but the primary key is auto increment. so, I can't figure where is the error laid.

Comment: Could you add the create script for your table to your question please? (Right Click -> Script Table As -> Create To)

Comment: @RichBenner : am I need to insert primary key while the key is auto increment?

Comment: @RichBenner : actually I don't create anyscript for that table because it is automatically created when I create Yii2 application.

Comment: @RichBenner : I've add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your issue is with the [password_reset_token] column.

You have a unique constraint on that column but it allows NULL values and you're not inserting data in this statement, that's why it's seeing the NULL as a duplicate key. You can either remove the unique constraint on this field or look at inserting unique data into this field.

Comment: but I need that column to be unique if the content of that column is not null. so, when password is not reseted, that column value is null, but when the password is reseted that column value is not null and unique. is it possible?

Comment: Not with a unique constraint on that column. You would be able to do it in your update statement that sets that figure but not within the table itself.